# Yaoi Manga where a guy gets stuck in a game and raises the male lead to become king

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this Yaoi about 2 years ago. It's about a guy that gets stuck in a game he plays and finds the male lead. He decides to raise him to become the king or something, but the male lead falls for him. The princess that wanted to marry him tried to put him under her control (kinda like brainwashing him into loving her) but the guy who raised him came out crying about how he didn't want the male lead to live like that. Then the male lead takes the guy back to the house and they do the deed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, as you may have noticed one of our community has removed your request for recommendations. If you take the [tour] and look at the [help], you'll see this site doesn't do recommendations. Also as this is a [tag:story-identification] take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) on asking good id questions.

Answer (score 2):

Is it **Everything for The Demon King Evelogia**? There's an anime about it too!

I think this story fits your description very well. Let me add some other details about the story and see if it really is the right one or not.

Ever since MC was a kid, instead of idolizing the heroes, he was obssessed with villains, particularly demon kings. He thought that they are very strong for being able to hold out for so long alone while heroes are weaker because they're always attacking together to survive /win. MC then died and got isekai-ed into his favorite game where he met his beloved demon king. However, the demon king was still a teenager and hasn't figured out that he's a demon king yet, he only knew that he got a strange but super strong power that scared everyone (except MC ofc). I think the demon king's family kept on trying to suppress his power and having him marry a princess but MC couldn't accept that, saying that a demon king should do whatever he wants and bows to no one!!! A demon king should use his incredibly strong power to his advantage and spread fear to those around him. He should be able to kill anyone who dares to oppose him or even kill people just for fun to fulfil his desires! Even the MC was ready to die happily in the hands of the demon king but the demon king refused to do that and fell in love with the MC instead and that's why they "did the deed" after that. MC was the uke, btw. The cute-looking demon king was the seme.